# Avoid Python lint warning for @dataclass variable declarations

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-dataclasses

I am having a try of the [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) feature in Python 3.7, but get this warning below word 'hue':

```
'hue' used before definition
Python (use-before-def)
```

I suppose it is a linter warrning. I tried several linters that python extension provided, but none of them work.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class Color:
    hue: int
    lightness: float = 2.0
c = Color(2)
```

Is there a way to have syntax checking etc enabled but avoid receiving this warning?

warning using pep8
[image: warning and err]

warning using pylint or mypy
[image: warning]

Comment: Could you include the version numbers of the various tools that are giving you this error?  Have you made sure that they're all updated to the latest versions?

Comment: the Python extension version is 2018.12.1

Answer (score 5):

You can set `"python.analysis.disabled": ["use-before-def"]` to disable the check ([docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_python-language-server-settings)). The mis-classification of this as an issue has been [reported](https://github.com/Microsoft/python-language-server/issues/395).